# Angular2 cannot use npm package 'ng2-bootstrap' datepicker component inside a [formGroup]

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

As the title suggests, I cannot use [bootstrap's ng2 datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker) inside an html element with a [formGroup] attribute.

Html is

```
<form [formGroup]="programForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="datePickerDate" value="{{datePickerDate}}" />
    <datepicker [(ngModel)]="datePickerDate"></datepicker>
</form>
```

programForm variable is defined as

```
  this.programForm = this.builder.group({
        datePickerDate: [this.selectedDate]
       })
```

When viewing this, is complains with

> ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent
>   formGroup directive.  Try using
>         formGroup's partner directive "formControlName" instead.  Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
>
>   Or, if you'd like to avoid registering this form control, indicate that it's standalone in ngModelOptions:
>
>   Example:
>
>
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>    <input formControlName="firstName">
>    <input [(ngModel)]="showMoreControls" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
> </div>
> ```

I tried adding

> [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

which solved the error and makes the datepicker appear to be working. However  when I select a date, it does not update the underlying variable. (it just updates the html)

I had a read on how Angular2 detects changes and I udnerstand why this is something angular2 wouldnt be able to pickup.

What I want is to simply have the underlying variable update when I selecte a date. But I cant seem to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: IIRC that team hasn't implemented reactive forms versions of their controls yet: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/893

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear. But that's helpful none the less. I will see if i can contribute with a PR maybe.

Comment: @nadlie please note that the ng-bootstrap project fully supports both template-driven and reactive forms (as well as many other goodies like datepickers in popups, multi-month view etc.): https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, is it possible to use `ng-bootstrap` with `bootstrap 3`?

Comment: @developer033 it is Bootstrap 4 only. This is based on decision of the Bootstrap's team to stop any development of Bootstrap 3 and fully focus on version 4.

Comment: Hmm :(, I was interested in migrate my projects from AngularJs to Angular2, however besides having to change the `JS/HTML` part I'd have to change all the `CSS` also (which is based on bootstrap 3). That's why I was asking. Thanks for info.